# Can I sign multisig transaction only with private key in a descriptor based wallet?

Tags: wallet, multi-signature, output-script-descriptors

I created a multisig wallet using bdk. It seems to accept descriptor with owner wallet's private key and other participating wallet's public key. Is it possible to create a multisig wallet where only one wallet can create transaction and will get access to other's public keys but other wallets don't need other participant's public keys for signing the transaction?

For example, If I create a 2 of 3 multisig with participants A,B,C. I created transaction with A who has access to public keys of both B and C using descriptor `thresh(key(A_xprv),key(B_xpub),key(C_xpub)` . Can I sign the transaction with B with only with its private key if it does not have access to public keys of A and C? I'm unable to create a descriptor which can sign the transaction for B without requiring public keys of A and C.

Comment: I find it hard to follow what you're trying to do. Could you please more explicitly describe the different signing scenarios that you want to combine?

Comment: @Murch Sorry if my language was confusing to understand. I want to know if there is a method where a participating wallet can sign a multisig transaction with only it's private key without requiring other wallet's public keys. For creating descriptor to sign transaction, I seem to need both my private key and other participant's public keys. I hope this makes a little more sense. I've also edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

All public keys or redeem script/witness script is required to sign the transaction when spending bitcoin multisig UTXO.

An experiment to see if you can sign the transaction without public keys:

1. Run `bitcoind -signet=1 -rpcport=38332 -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=password`
2. Create 3 wallets m1, m2 and m3

   ```
   $ bitcoin-cli -named createwallet wallet_name=m1 descriptors=false
   ```
3. Get 3 public keys from each wallet:

   ```
   $ bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=m1 getnewaddress

   tb1q8hz93lwkmzjq2yapxr6mnsfwjt5wvp2f5zgm98

   $ bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=m1 getaddressinfo tb1q8hz93lwkmzjq2yapxr6mnsfwjt5wvp2f5zgm98

   {
     "address": "tb1q8hz93lwkmzjq2yapxr6mnsfwjt5wvp2f5zgm98",
     "scriptPubKey": "00143dc458fdd6d8a40513a130f5b9c12e92e8e60549",
     "ismine": true,
     "solvable": true,
     "desc": "wpkh([045471ed/0'/0'/1']039927842080cc4a22d2d4a63c13b3d9a66564e230775981f03976787afe6cf716)#wht4f5zk",
     "iswatchonly": false,
     "isscript": false,
     "iswitness": true,
     "witness_version": 0,
     "witness_program": "3dc458fdd6d8a40513a130f5b9c12e92e8e60549",
     "pubkey": "039927842080cc4a22d2d4a63c13b3d9a66564e230775981f03976787afe6cf716",
     "ischange": false,
     "timestamp": 1663309171,
     "hdkeypath": "m/0'/0'/1'",
     "hdseedid": "ccd54fe6a42efde5251f8443f1edd7ebcf25fefa",
     "hdmasterfingerprint": "045471ed",
     "labels": [
       ""
     ]
   }
   ```
4. Create 2 of 3 multisig with the public keys:

   ```
   $ bitcoin-cli createmultisig 2 "[\"039927842080cc4a22d2d4a63c13b3d9a66564e230775981f03976787afe6cf716\",\"0359591df29bbcdb8fb2e4cde5d92ecc8c6698d9f0ab27f2f76938cdddc2323279\",\"037e44526a83fdb2c89de80356eeda1bbfdb3738a1b3b70c3c71ea95feaeec4046\"]"

   {
     "address": "2N7WpySLj8bBGFrZE8hxQUm29ZCwaqz5FvT",
     "redeemScript": "5221039927842080cc4a22d2d4a63c13b3d9a66564e230775981f03976787afe6cf716210359591df29bbcdb8fb2e4cde5d92ecc8c6698d9f0ab27f2f76938cdddc232327921037e44526a83fdb2c89de80356eeda1bbfdb3738a1b3b70c3c71ea95feaeec404653ae",
     "descriptor": "sh(multi(2,039927842080cc4a22d2d4a63c13b3d9a66564e230775981f03976787afe6cf716,0359591df29bbcdb8fb2e4cde5d92ecc8c6698d9f0ab27f2f76938cdddc2323279,037e44526a83fdb2c89de80356eeda1bbfdb3738a1b3b70c3c71ea95feaeec4046))#jqk9dcqj"
   }
   ```
5. Send 0.001 sBTC to multisig address using [signet faucet](https://signet.bc-2.jp/): [`0b30a06e2653b84b0b976559a0efc9018a6da2a4ea6c71c346496d2ac36e43b5`](https://mempool.space/signet/tx/0b30a06e2653b84b0b976559a0efc9018a6da2a4ea6c71c346496d2ac36e43b5)
6. Create a PSBT to spend this UTXO:

   ```
   $ bitcoin-cli createpsbt "[{\"txid\":\"0b30a06e2653b84b0b976559a0efc9018a6da2a4ea6c71c346496d2ac36e43b5\",\"vout\":1}]" "[{\"tb1qvl3a3l8ejuyk62qfz2kjjxdndcrk99ldxchqvx\":\"0.0009\"}]" 

   cHNidP8BAFICAAAAAbVDbsMqbUlGw3Fs6qSibYoBye+gWWWXC0u4UyZuoDALAQAAAAD9////AZBfAQAAAAAAFgAUZ+PY/PmXCW0oCRKtKRmzbgdil+0AAAAAAAAA
   ```
7. You will get `"complete": false` in the output if you try signing it with any 2 wallets using `walletprocesspsbt` or individually sign, combine with `combinepsbt` followed by `finalizepsbt`
8. Import multisig address in m1, descriptor (has all public keys) in m2 and redeemscript in m3 wallet:

```
$ bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=m1 importmulti '[{ "scriptPubKey": { "address": "2N7WpySLj8bBGFrZE8hxQUm29ZCwaqz5FvT" }, "timestamp":"now", "watchonly": true }]'

 [
   {
     "success": true
   }
 ]
```

```
$ bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=m2 importmulti '[{ "desc": "sh(multi(2,039927842080cc4a22d2d4a63c13b3d9a66564e230775981f03976787afe6cf716,0359591df29bbcdb8fb2e4cde5d92ecc8c6698d9f0ab27f2f76938cdddc2323279,037e44526a83fdb2c89de80356eeda1bbfdb3738a1b3b70c3c71ea95feaeec4046))#jqk9dcqj", "timestamp":"now", "watchonly": true }]'

 [
   {
     "success": true
   }
 ]
```

```
$ bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=m3 importmulti '[{ "scriptPubKey": "a9149c85346a6ea0c2b6c6904e5c464df6ef84fe170587", "redeemscript": "5221039927842080cc4a22d2d4a63c13b3d9a66564e230775981f03976787afe6cf716210359591df29bbcdb8fb2e4cde5d92ecc8c6698d9f0ab27f2f76938cdddc232327921037e44526a83fdb2c89de80356eeda1bbfdb3738a1b3b70c3c71ea95feaeec404653ae", "timestamp":"now", "watchonly": true }]'

 [
   {
     "success": true
   }
 ]
```

9. Try signing it with m1 and m2 or m1 and m3. It won't work.

   ```
   $ bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=m1 walletprocesspsbt cHNidP8BAFICAAAAAbVDbsMqbUlGw3Fs6qSibYoBye+gWWWXC0u4UyZuoDALAQAAAAD9////AZBfAQAAAAAAFgAUZ+PY/PmXCW0oCRKtKRmzbgdil+0AAAAAAAAA
   {
     "psbt": "cHNidP8BAFICAAAAAbVDbsMqbUlGw3Fs6qSibYoBye+gWWWXC0u4UyZuoDALAQAAAAD9////AZBfAQAAAAAAFgAUZ+PY/PmXCW0oCRKtKRmzbgdil+0AAAAAAAEAcgIAAAABf9MjFLP83xBP8nl17j6VId+Y2UW/5seoLnxCqNnLOAcAAAAAAP7///8CMew0w1QGAAAWABRA3SSDttwD9s5g86KiG+bhufb1caCGAQAAAAAAF6kUnIU0am6gwrbGkE5cRk3274T+FwWH1qYBAAAA",
     "complete": false
   }

   $ bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=m2 walletprocesspsbt cHNidP8BAFICAAAAAbVDbsMqbUlGw3Fs6qSibYoBye+gWWWXC0u4UyZuoDALAQAAAAD9////AZBfAQAAAAAAFgAUZ+PY/PmXCW0oCRKtKRmzbgdil+0AAAAAAAEAcgIAAAABf9MjFLP83xBP8nl17j6VId+Y2UW/5seoLnxCqNnLOAcAAAAAAP7///8CMew0w1QGAAAWABRA3SSDttwD9s5g86KiG+bhufb1caCGAQAAAAAAF6kUnIU0am6gwrbGkE5cRk3274T+FwWH1qYBAAAA
   {
     "psbt": "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",
     "complete": false
   }
   ```

   However, it will work with m2 and m3:

   ```
   $ bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=m2 walletprocesspsbt cHNidP8BAFICAAAAAbVDbsMqbUlGw3Fs6qSibYoBye+gWWWXC0u4UyZuoDALAQAAAAD9////AZBfAQAAAAAAFgAUZ+PY/PmXCW0oCRKtKRmzbgdil+0AAAAAAAAA
   {
     "psbt": "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",
     "complete": false
   }

   $ bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=m3 walletprocesspsbt 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
   {
     "psbt": "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",
     "complete": true
   }
   ```
10. This transaction can be finalized and broadcasted:

    ```
    $ bitcoin-cli finalizepsbt 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
    {
      "hex": "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",
      "complete": true
    }

    $ bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction 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

    6f56b1b93a6053cb9e7b91ae4786a20f8d34f1d183022142c2fbf8a16d780766
    ```

Tx: [`6f56b1b93a6053cb9e7b91ae4786a20f8d34f1d183022142c2fbf8a16d780766`](https://mempool.space/signet/tx/6f56b1b93a6053cb9e7b91ae4786a20f8d34f1d183022142c2fbf8a16d780766)

You might also find this interesting: https://github.com/1440000bytes/p2p

Comment: So, we need to have public keys of all A, B, C in all three wallets?

Comment: Yes. You can even try this experiment in bitcoin core. I will update the answer with some steps in some time.

Comment: Thanks. Will wait for the update.